# Is possible to see the content of the Java String pool?

Tags: java, string, jvm, pool

I was studying and reading about Java String pool and I did some examples to understand this feature, but I have a doubt: Is possible, is there a way to access or see the content of the string pool?

Comment: I think all you can get out of it is statistics (`-XX:+PrintStringTableStatistics`), not the actual content.

Comment: You can ask a specific question about your doubt too.

Comment: Chances are very high that you can't; such a pool, if it exists at all, is an implementation detail of the JVM, therefore it is highly unlikely that an API exists to access it.

Comment: @fge Just because it's an implementation detail, it doesn't mean you can't access it using diagnostic tools, just look at the things Java Flight Recorder does.

Comment: If you are using openJDK/hotspot JVM, than there is much easier solution, than replacing rt.jar with hook for strings (which also is incorrect). You can use Serviceability Agent, which is VM-specific (and that's exactly how Flight Recorder works). If someone will re-open answer I can show the actual code for attaching to jvm and printing string pool's content

Comment: That will be nice, because the answers in the other questions are not accepted and also they don't answer my question? thanks @qwwdfsad

Comment: You can try to flag the question for moderator attention

Comment: Yes it is possible if you run Oracle JDK / OpenJDK. [ServiceabilityAgent](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/docs/Serviceability.html#bsa) can do this. See [example](https://github.com/odnoklassniki/jvm-serviceability-examples/blob/master/src/demo3/InternedStrings.java).